Import fails with certain subdirectory name

I attempt to import a Python module that's in a subdirectory of my
current working directory.
If I name the subdirectory foo_bar or one_two_three or python_foo, the import succeeds.
But if I name the subdirectory python_utils, the import fails:

02:27: droot ⦿ tree
.
└── python_utils
    └── dostuff.py

2 directories, 1 file

02:27: droot ⦿ python
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr 17 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 14.0.1 20240411 (Red Hat 14.0.1-0)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from python_utils.dostuff import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_utils.dostuff'
>>> 

02:27: droot ⦿ mv python_utils/ foo_bar/

02:27: droot ⦿ python
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr 17 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 14.0.1 20240411 (Red Hat 14.0.1-0)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from foo_bar.dostuff import foo
>>> 

02:28: droot ⦿ mv foo_bar/ one_two_three/

02:29: droot ⦿ python
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr 17 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 14.0.1 20240411 (Red Hat 14.0.1-0)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from one_two_three.dostuff import foo
>>> 

02:35: droot ⦿ mv one_two_three/ python_foo

02:37: droot ⦿python
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr 17 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 14.0.1 20240411 (Red Hat 14.0.1-0)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from python_foo.dostuff import foo
>>>


What's going on?   I have tried many names, and all work except python_utils!


It looks like the python_utils package is already installed in your system, and that package wouldn't have your custom subpackage dostuff. You can verify this by running import python_utils and print(python_utils) and it may indicate where that package is (or help(python_utils) which may indicate members that you can actually import for you to resolve where that is).

@metatoaster That would not explain the successful imports of foo_bar.dostuff, one_two_three.dostuff and python_foo.dostuff.

Yes it would, because the availability of python_utils as an import at the site-package level would block the import from anywhere else as it wasn't declared as a namespace package, so the import of anything not in the "main" package would fail. As opposed to foo_bar and one_two_three where no such package exist as a site-package. Moreover, the message "No module named 'python_utils.dostuff'" indicates that python_utils.dostuff is not imported, because there is no python_utils.dostuff at the site-package as python failed to load that from the site-package python_utils.

Thanks guys - yes, I didn't realise, but it seems I had a PyPI package called python-utils installed globally, and when pip installs a  package with a dash/hyphen in the name, it changes the dash to an underscore, so it can be imported by import statement rather than needing importlib; so the name clashed with my own package.
@metatoaster if you post as an answer I will accept.
